# Can't paste with CMD+V in "Go to the folder" in Inttellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

While this is a small issue, but annoying nevertheless.

When opening a new project from Intellij idea, I cannot use CMD+V to paste the Path. When I try to do that I hear the dreaded bell! This is the dialog box I'm talking about -

[image]

And this is while, if I right-click, I can see paste and then it works. [image]

I wanted to know if I'm the only one facing this issue (or only one annoyed with this one) And if there is a solution to this.

I'm using Intellij Idea 2019.2 Community edition on Mac OS Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue, please vote for it: [IDEA-137638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137638)